# Continue from the last counter when reopen the android application

Tags: android, save

I am new in Android programing. I want to make an application. The button text increase whenever the user click on it. My counter is reseted when the application is closed. How can I store the last counter value and call it again when the application is reopened?

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c++;
            button.setText(Integer.toString(c));
        }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT:
I try to use this [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) but I got eror about  "setSilent" and "mSilentMode". Help please

My new code

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private int c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
    setSilent(silent);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c++;
            button.setText(Integer.toString(c));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: you can save counter in shared preferences and when you open again get value from shared prefrences.

Comment: Please clarify if you need to preserved across different lifespans or across a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, are you asking how to preserve a variable across an app's lifespan or between different lifespans?

If it's across different lifespans, you can write it to disk and then read it `onCreate`.

If you need to do it across one lifespan, it depends on your use case, but generally putting it in a global, static variable would do the trick!

If this is unclear and you'd like some sample code, please, don't be afraid to ask! : )

Comment: I had no idea about it until reading your answer. Now, I think that I need to write it to disk. What is the way? What is the name of the method?

Comment: I can write down a sample for you, but I think the most educational and future proof way would be to read this article, from the android academy, on the topic: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html I used it myself, when first needing to handle reading and writing, it proved to be most helpful! : )

Comment: The methods that you need to care about, from what I've gathered from your question are SharedPreferences and internal/external storage. The latter would be my personal recommendation, for your specific use case, as it's not a setting, but rather a data value.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your c value in the Preference when your activity is going to be closed, and when you rise up your activity you set your c variabile to the previous value

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet out of your onClickListener: To get the int if there is any

```
SharedPreferences hhii = getSharedPreferences("c_value", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int ca = hhii.getInt("c_value2", 0);
    button.setText(ca+"");
```

Use this in your onClickListener: To save the int as the user clicks the button-much better than saving it in onBackPressed or OnDestroy or whatever

```
 c++;
                button.setText(Integer.toString(c));
                SharedPreferences hhii = getSharedPreferences("c_value", MODE_PRIVATE);
                hhii.edit().putInt("c_value2",c).commit();
```

Regards from Iran,
   Gabriel

Comment: It worked thank you. But I have a question. Why is your method better than saving it in onStop?

Comment: It is easier. Because you don't have to write it again in onDestroy and onStop,etc. Remember to check the answer as the best one! Glad it worked

Comment: It is not better. This is accessing memory per item click, updating it needlessly. You should update it on pause. And also, @ffttyy remember to upvote/accept the helpful answers to your question.

Comment: @ffttyy   Thanks! I wonder if managing memory usage is necessary for simple apps?(Containing a few TextViews, Images, WebViews, etc)

Comment: It's a question of exercising good practice, not necessity. Putting the little extra effort here will pay off in the long run. : )